# OpenGL glDrawArraysInstanced faster than glDrawElementsInstanced: Is there a way to make glDrawElementsInstanced faster?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, geometry-instancing

I'm making tests with OpenGL instancing methods and I tested both glDrawArraysInstanced and glDrawElementsInstanced functions with the rest of the code being practically the same. The test is to render 1 million colored squares (scaled to become pixels and fit in the screen) that can rotate and translate too, and see the FPS difference. 
The results I had are:

- **With glDrawArraysInstanced: 36-39 FPS**
- **With glDrawElementsInstanced: 24-28 FPS**

I didn't have a conclusion on which function should be faster based on my research, I would prefer to use glDrawElementsInstanced, though.

So my question is if there's a way of improving glDrawElementsInstanced in this case (or in general) so that drawing with it is equivalent or faster than glDrawArraysInstanced. 
Here's the code I used for glDrawArraysInstanced:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int width = 1000, height = 600;
SDLWindow window(width, height, "window");
const char* glsl_version = "#version 330";

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

Shader shader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/shader.frag");

float quadVertices[] = {
    // positions     
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,

    -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f
};

float colors[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};

// Gera VAO e buffers
GLuint VBO, VAO, TRANSFORM;

unsigned int amount = 1000000;

glm::mat4 *modelMatrices;
modelMatrices = new glm::mat4[amount];

GLsizei vec4Size = sizeof(glm::vec4);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &TRANSFORM);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// configuração de VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices) + sizeof(colors), nullptr, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(quadVertices), quadVertices);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices), sizeof(colors), colors);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)(sizeof(quadVertices)));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// configuração de TRANSFORM
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TRANSFORM);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, amount * sizeof(glm::vec2) + amount * sizeof(glm::vec2) + amount * sizeof(glm::vec4), nullptr, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec2), (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec2), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount));
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec4), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount + sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);

glBindVertexArray(0);

MathUtils mu;

vector <float> randNumbers;

float amountSqrt = glm::sqrt(amount);

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    randNumbers.push_back(mu.GenRandFloat(-1.0f, 1.0f) * amountSqrt);
}
glm::vec2 *scale = new glm::vec2[amount];
glm::vec2 *translate = new glm::vec2[amount];
glm::vec4 *rotate = new glm::vec4[amount];

void *transformBfrPtr = nullptr;

bool quit = 0;
while (!quit)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shader.use();

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TRANSFORM);
    transformBfrPtr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        scale[i][0] = 1.0f / amountSqrt;
        scale[i][1] = 1.0f / amountSqrt;
    }

    std::memcpy(transformBfrPtr, scale, sizeof(scale[0]) * amount);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);


    transformBfrPtr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        translate[i][0] = randNumbers[i];
        translate[i][1] = randNumbers[amount - i];
    }

    std::memcpy(transformBfrPtr, translate, sizeof(translate[0]) * amount);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);


    transformBfrPtr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount + sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, sizeof(glm::vec4) * amount, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);

    float var = SDL_GetTicks() / 1000.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        rotate[i][0] = cos(var);
        rotate[i][1] = sin(var);
        rotate[i][2] = -sin(var);
        rotate[i][3] = cos(var);
    }

    std::memcpy(transformBfrPtr, rotate, sizeof(rotate[0]) * amount);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6, amount);

    switch (window.SDL_ManageEvent())
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        SDL_Quit();
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        break;
    }

    window.SDL_SwapWindow();
}


return 0;
}
```

And the code that uses glDrawElementsInstanced (almost the same but with indices):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int width = 1000, height = 600;
SDLWindow window(width, height, "window");
const char* glsl_version = "#version 330";

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

Shader shader("shaders/shader.vert", "shaders/shader.frag");

float quadVertices[] = {
    // positions     
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f
};

float colors[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 1, 3
};

// Gera VAO e buffers
GLuint VBO, VAO, TRANSFORM, EBO;

unsigned int amount = 1000000;

glm::mat4 *modelMatrices;
modelMatrices = new glm::mat4[amount];

GLsizei vec4Size = sizeof(glm::vec4);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &TRANSFORM);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// configuração de VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices) + sizeof(colors), nullptr, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(quadVertices), quadVertices);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices), sizeof(colors), colors);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)(sizeof(quadVertices)));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

// configuração de EBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

// configuração de TRANSFORM
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TRANSFORM);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, amount * sizeof(glm::vec2) + amount * sizeof(glm::vec2) + amount * sizeof(glm::vec4), nullptr, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec2), (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec2), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount));
glVertexAttribPointer(4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec4), (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount + sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(4);
glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1);
glVertexAttribDivisor(4, 1);

glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

MathUtils mu;

vector <float> randNumbers;

float amountSqrt = glm::sqrt(amount);

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    randNumbers.push_back(mu.GenRandFloat(-1.0f, 1.0f) * amountSqrt);
}
glm::vec2 *scale = new glm::vec2[amount];
glm::vec2 *translate = new glm::vec2[amount];
glm::vec4 *rotate = new glm::vec4[amount];

void *transformBfrPtr = nullptr;

bool quit = 0;
while (!quit)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shader.use();

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TRANSFORM);
    transformBfrPtr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        scale[i][0] = 1.0f / amountSqrt;
        scale[i][1] = 1.0f / amountSqrt;
    }

    std::memcpy(transformBfrPtr, scale, sizeof(scale[0]) * amount);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);


    transformBfrPtr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        translate[i][0] = randNumbers[i];
        translate[i][1] = randNumbers[amount - i];
    }

    std::memcpy(transformBfrPtr, translate, sizeof(translate[0]) * amount);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);


    transformBfrPtr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount + sizeof(glm::vec2) * amount, sizeof(glm::vec4) * amount, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);

    float var = SDL_GetTicks() / 1000.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        rotate[i][0] = cos(var);
        rotate[i][1] = sin(var);
        rotate[i][2] = -sin(var);
        rotate[i][3] = cos(var);
    }

    std::memcpy(transformBfrPtr, rotate, sizeof(rotate[0]) * amount);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, amount);

    switch (window.SDL_ManageEvent())
    {
    case SDL_QUIT:
        SDL_Quit();
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        break;
    }

    window.SDL_SwapWindow();
}


return 0;
}
```

The vertex shader code if it helps:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 scale;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 translation;
layout (location = 4) in vec4 rotation;

out vec3 color;

void main()
{
    mat2 rotation = mat2(rotation.xy, rotation.zw);
    gl_Position =  vec4(((aPos * rotation + translation) *  scale) , 0.0, 1.0);

    color = aColor;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, it seems I have a problem that's not related to any of this. I tested both codes in another machine and was surprised by the results. First some context:
The tests above were made on this (PC) setup: 
16GB ram, i7 4790k, GTX 970.

Then I made the same tests on my laptop with this setup: 
8GB ram, i5 8250u, Geforce MX150 (2GB)

Results:

- **With glDrawArraysInstanced: 73-87 FPS**
- **With glDrawElementsInstanced: 74-87 FPS**

I also noticed that in my laptop the GPU usage was around 99% all the time, while in my PC it was around 45% with glDrawElementsInstanced and with glDrawArraysInstanced oscilating around 60%. The CPU usage is bellow 60% in all cores in both cases (so CPU bottleneck is out of question).
I tried to uninstall GPU drivers and make a clean reinstall using DDU, but it didn't work.
I also checked the Nvidia control painel in both systems and the setup is exactly the same. I have Windows 10 installed in both machines and they are setup to maximum performance on Windows control painel.
My initial question is partially answered since I have VERY different FPS results (between draw call functions themselves) in different machines. 
How such a difference is possible? Any sugestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you test in another graphics card, better a different vendor?

Comment: I updated the topic to show the tests I made on my laptop too.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a resolution on this? I am looking at the same problem now.